# How to paginate the result to a certain depth?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm using Memgraph and I was wondering about how can I paginate the result to a certain depth to build a knowledge graph and display it?
I'm looking for a certain query I can use in Memgraph Lab in order to achieve this